# Alasql - Create Excel with Wraptext and Multiple Sheets

Tags: javascript, xlsx, xls, alasql

I need to create an Excel file with multiple sheets and wraptext.

When I use XLSX, I am able to create the multiple sheets. But wraptext is not working with xlsx.

I have been able to do wraptext with XLS, but this time multiple sheets are not working.

Any suggestion how to get wraptext and multiple sheets in one workbook to work with either XLS or XLSX using alasql?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Checked it. Thanks for that.